# jaxws web-service. Changing nodes structure

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I have next code in my Entity class

```
class Role {  
private List<String> tubes;  
//...  
}
```

Next Maven generate request-response classes, using **jaxws-maven-plugin**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "getRoleResponse", namespace = "http://ws.config.com/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getRoleResponse", namespace = "http://ws.config.com/")
public class GetRoleResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return", namespace = "")
    private Role _return;
//...

}
```

I send soap request and get response like

```
<tubes>1SO</tubes>
<tubes>2SO</tubes>
<tubes>3SO</tubes>
<tubes>4SO</tubes>
```

But I want get request like:

```
<tubes> 
    <tube>1SO</tube>
    <tube>2SO</tube>
    <tube>3SO</tube>
    <tube>4SO</tube>  
</tubes>
```

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

Part of generated WSDL

```
<xs:complexType name="role">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tubes" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. way:

   - specify the XSD
   - generate the JAXB classes
   - use the generated JAXB classes in your Web Service
2. way:

   - manually annotate the Role class with JAXB annotations as needed, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html might help (personally, I seldom annotate JAXB classes manually. I usually generate them from XSD files)

Comment: Yep, second way is helpful. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Change your `List<String>` to a `List<Tube>` and create a type `Tube` with a string element

Comment: This will be helpful, but I have many List<String> fields and I don't want create new class for every field

Comment: @user1143825 looks like the second option of Puce could be quite helpful